# Socket Connection between Python and Dart, dont get all data

Tags: python, flutter, sockets, dart

i have a Python server socket which send me data in json Format, and a Flutter (dart) Application which receive this data. My Problem is i dont get all data, just a few lines.
I dont understand where the problem is?! Its the Server or the Client

Python CODE: (socket server)

```
import socket
from SqlServerRequest import SqlServerRequest


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('192.168.16.126', 4567))
s.listen(5)



while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")
    data = clientsocket.recv(2048).decode()
    print(data)
    if data == "exit":
       break
    d= str(SqlServerRequest.readData())
    clientsocket.sendall(bytes(d,"utf-8"))

    clientsocket.close()
```

Dart Code: (Client)

```
class SocketConnection {

  SocketConnection();

Future<String> con() async{
String indexRequest = 'FLUTTER GET / HTTP/1.1\nConnection: close\n\n';
String d;



 await Socket.connect('192.168.16.126', 4567).then((socket) {
  print('Connected to: '
      '${socket.remoteAddress.address}:${socket.remotePort}');

  //Establish the onData, and onDone callbacks
  socket.listen((data) {
    d = String.fromCharCodes(data);
    print(d);

  }, onDone: () {
    print("Done");
    socket.write("Erhalten");
    socket.destroy();
  });

  //Send the request
  socket.write(indexRequest);

});
return d;
}
}
```

Comment: You have to loop reading until you have everything you expect.

Comment: @user207421 Thank you for your quick answer, but I have no idea how to do that, do you have any examples?

Comment: I solved my problem, it wasnt even one, the console just didnt show me all data :D